# Multiple Preview images diffrent height and width using cropit

Tags: jquery, image, resize, crop

Crop and resize images is a common issue build cms, so i found great plugin [here](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit)
that plugin working well in desktop and mobile touch screen but i have last issue in my project how can i make multiple preview in this page !

already look at the issue there and found someone post same like me issue, so i digging on here but not working, issue [here](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/138)

then i checked jquery.cropit.js line 927 has class cropit-image-preview means will load images, so i make

```
  <form action="#">
  <div class="image-editor">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
    <div class="cropit-image-preview"></div>
    <div class="image-size-label">
      Resize image
    </div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>

  <!--diffrent class with cropit-image-preview with diffrent height and width-->
   <div class="image-editor-test">
    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input">
    <div class="cropit-image-preview-test"></div>
    <div class="image-size-label">
      Resize image
    </div>
    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">
    <input type="hidden" name="image-data" class="hidden-image-data" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
```

Then i copy the jquery.cropit.js and rename it and also change line 927 become **cropit-image-preview-test** and also the css is here

```
.cropit-image-preview {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    cursor: move;
  }

   .cropit-image-preview-test {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
    background-size: cover;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    cursor: move;
  }
```

and this is my js

```
$(function() {
    $('.image-editor').cropit();

    $('form').submit(function() {
       var imageData = $('.image-editor').cropit('export');
       $('.hidden-image-data').val(imageData);
       var formValue = $(this).serialize();
       $('#result-data').text(formValue);
      return false;
    });

    <!--test preview image-->
    $('.image-editor-test').cropit();

    $('form#test').submit(function() {
       var imageData = $('.image-editor-test').cropit('export');
       $('.hidden-image-data-test').val(imageData);
       var formValue = $(this).serialize();
       $('#result-data-test').text(formValue);
      return false;
    });

  });
```

to be honest this came from demo [here](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/blob/master/demo/form.html) and [issue](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit/issues/138) but the author nothing respond and someone already post in stackoverflow but nothing clear explation, Thanks for any comment

Answer (score 0):

I think the first thing I want to mention is that by default, the cropit plugin works out of the box with two different size previews. You just need to add a class to the "cropit-preview" in order to style it.  [Here is a JSfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgoezkmn/1/). The main issue I see in the above code is that you changed the preview class from "cropit-image-preview" to "cropit-image-preview-test" for the second preview class. This should not change.

Also, in the most recent version of the cropit plugin (which I believe is 0.5), this preview class and it's surrounding helper classes have changed. I know you copied this from another source, but I would make sure you are using the most recent version before trying to fix this issue. You can view the docs on their Github: //github.com/scottcheng/cropit

**MY EXAMPLE:**

If you wanted to get rid of the ugly file upload buttons, follow the example below. [Here is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4t5sjb5/2/) for full working example and reference. I also included the cropit plugin in the Javascript section since it is not on a CDN, so you will need to scroll all the way down to see the embed codes for the page (I removed them in the on-page examples).

**NOTE:** *I am not showing what to do with the image in order to upload and pass it to the server since this was not part of the question. In my application I took care of this process during the form submission.*

**JAVASCRIPT**

I assigned each cropit to a variable so we could use it later in the script (In this example it was used in the timeout function).

```
var memberCropper = $('#image-cropper');

var ballotCropper = $('#ballot-image-cropper');
```

Then the cropit method was initialized with some options included (yours will probably be different depending on your application).

```
memberCropper.cropit({
  imageBackground: true,
  imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 10
});

ballotCropper.cropit({
  imageBackground: true,
  imageBackgroundBorderWidth: 10
});
```

Then I added an onclick function for the button I created for each cropit. This allows you to hide the ugly default file select options.

```
$('.select-image-btn').click(function() {
    memberCropper.find('.cropit-image-input').click();
});

$('.ballot-select-image-btn').click(function() {
    ballotCropper.find('.cropit-image-input').click();
});
```

**CSS**

The CSS located in the fiddle was a compiled LESS file so that is why it looks like a lot, but you will need to separate your styles for each cropit that you create in order to change the dimensions of each preview. I will assume that you will have your own way of finishing your stylings.

**HTML**

Here is the full HTML for the two sections.

```html
<div id="ballot-image-cropper">
  <div class="ballot-select-image-btn btn btn-success">Update Ballot Image</div>

    <div class="cropit-preview ballot-cropit-preview"></div>

    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">

    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" name="ballotImage" id="ballotImage" />
</div>


<div id="image-cropper">
  <div class="select-image-btn btn btn-success">Add Member Image</div>
    <div class="cropit-preview"></div>

    <input type="range" class="cropit-image-zoom-input">

    <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" name="memberImage" id="memberImage" />
  </div>
```